# Failed to connect to FTP Server musingsofamaverick.org:21

Tags: wordpress, ftp

"To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host."

I am my own host (my own computer, server, etc) and have not set up any FTP credentials so I can't update, install plugins or download themes.

This is an old problem, but I can only find old answers that don't appear to work with the current version of wordpress 5.5.3 on my server. I would rather avoid setting up an FTP server as that opens doors I would prefer remain closed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Need to add

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

to /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php.